# How to save console output in XCode Playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, macos-mojave, createml

**XCode 10.0 beta 3**,
**Mac Mojave 10.14 Beta**

I am using

**MLImageClassifier**(**trainingData**: MLImageClassifier.DataSource,
 **parameters**: MLImageClassifier.ModelParameters)

from **CreateML-Framework** to create a custom mlmodel in **XCode Playground**.

This method generates the following

[image: console_output.png]

I would like to save this output to a text file, but I don't know how to access the data and I can't find the location where it is produced.

I am thankful for every help.